# Как нарисовать рваную линию?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Есть ли возможность, стандартная, а если и нет, то скажите, как можно нарисовать рваную линию, похожу на баллончик, или рваную кисть, которая не полностью зарисовывает область, а как бы оставляет след. Я реализовываю такую вот [штуку](http://balticmaps.eu/merry-christmas/en/). Заранее, спасибо за помощь.

[Обновление] Задача упростилась, теперь просто нужно узнать как рисовать линию изображением.

Comment: Я так понимаю, единственный вариант это накрадывать одно и то же изображение снова и снова, каждый раз, когда курсор смещается.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko это да, но как бы это реализовать в коде, мне не просто не нужно рисовать, и ещё, соответствовать условиям которые выше, то есть, я хочу реализовать стирание картинки, как бы картинкой, но что бы не просто квадрат рисовался, а что бы в местах картинки, где пустота, у меня и не происходило этого стирания. Это как рисовать широкой кистью, где то остаётся краска, где то нет.

Comment: в том примере, который у вас просто рисуется одно и то же изображение, именно так, как я описал в комментарии выше. просто изображение необычной формы и по краям, судя по всему есть полупрозрачные пиксели.

Comment: если предположить, что у вас есть заднее изображение и переднее. то вам надо по клику в переднем изображении создавать прозрачный кусок установленной формы. вот пример в SO как это сделать  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690576/subtract-one-image-from-another-ios

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko тадададам, это то что мне нужно, буду копать в том направлении, предлагаю вам вынести это в ответ, я его зачту)) спасибо))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понимаю, единственный вариант это накладывать одно и то же изображение снова и снова, каждый раз, когда курсор смещается.

В том примере, который у вас просто рисуется одно и то же изображение, именно так, как я описал в комментарии выше. просто изображение необычной формы и по краям, судя по всему есть полупрозрачные пиксели.

если предположить, что у вас есть заднее изображение и переднее. то вам надо по клику в переднем изображении создавать прозрачный кусок установленной формы. вот [пример с SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690576/subtract-one-image-from-another-ios) как это сделать

```
// get access to the image bytes
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));

// create a buffer to hold the mask values
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);    
uint8_t *maskData = malloc(width * height);

// iterate over the pixel data, reading the alpha value
uint8_t *alpha = (uint8_t *)CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData) + 3;
uint8_t *mask = maskData;
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        *mask = *alpha;
        mask++;      
        alpha += 4;  // skip to the next pixel
    }
}

// create the mask image from the buffer
CGDataProviderRef maskProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, maskData, width * height, NULL);
CGImageRef maskImage = CGImageMaskCreate(width, height, 8, 8, width, maskProvider, NULL, false);

// cleanup
CFRelease(pixelData);
CFRelease(maskProvider);
free(maskData);
```

Потом, чтобы все это запустить сделать:

```
CGImageRef subtractedImage = CGImageCreateWithMask(b.CGImage, maskImage);
```

Еще добавлю, что этот фокус скорее всего будет есть очень много ресурсов для большой картинки. может есть смысл поделить на несколько маленьких.

Comment: а как бы двигать эту картинку?? то есть всегда обрезается все по центру, есть предположения??

Comment: не уверен что понял вопрос :( @ИльяТерезников

Comment: да я и сам себя запутал, все, разобрался со всем. Кстати, вы правы были, это все очень ресурсоемко))

Answer (score 0):

Менее ресурсоемким решением было бы использование `GLKit`, работало бы быстро и на всех девайсах, но не на всех `iOS`, кажется начиная с `iOS 7`. С другой стороны, можно поиграться с `CGPath`, `UIBezierPath`, маской картинкой и получить "почти" тот же результат, ключевое слово почти :)

**UPD:** Приведу пару ссылок

- [Линк 1](http://new2objectivec.blogspot.md/2011/07/image-mask-test-project.html)
- [Линк 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784475/erasing-on-uiimageview)
- [Линк 3](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/80991-erase-with-textures-in-opengl-1-1.html)